# Create annotation features programatically

Tags: arcgis-server, annotation, arcgis-silverlight-api

I am using the ESRI Silverlight API for my application. For points, polylines and polygons the Editor class combined with feature layers works great. But it looks like I have encountered a problem. My client needs to add/edit/delete annotations. I created an annotation layer and was able to publish it through ArcGIS Server but obviously couldn't edit it through the API because it's not supported.
From the research I did, I couldn't find an answer which lead me to something.

Is there a way how this can be achieved through arcpy / webservice / arcobjects / anything ?